# CKeditor own plugin with dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have written own plugin which generates a simple link. 
The strange thing is that I can not editing "href" attribute. Other attributes can be edited.

This element does not work:

```
{
    type: 'text',
    id: 'url',
    label: 'URL',
    commit: function(element) {
        element.setAttribute('href', this.getValue());
    },
    setup: function(element) {
        this.setValue(element.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}
```

When I create a link, href attribute is written. When I editing a link "href" attribute is not changed. Strange!

When I change the code above and rewrite name of attribute for example to "href-s":

```
{
    type: 'text',
    id: 'url',
    label: 'URL',
    commit: function(element) {
        element.setAttribute('href-s', this.getValue());
    },
    setup: function(element) {
        this.setValue(element.getAttribute('href-s'));
    }
}
```

Creation and editing attribute works perfectly.

You do not know what's the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For various internal reasons, CKEditor uses `data-cke-saved-href` attribute to duplicate `href` during runtime. So what in the output would look like

```
<p>I&#39;m a <a href="http://foo.com">plain&nbsp;link</a>.</p>

<p>I&#39;m a <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=Subject&amp;body=Body">mailto link</a>.</p>
```

is actually something different in editor DOM

```
<p>I'm a <a data-cke-saved-href="http://foo.com" href="http://foo.com">plain&nbsp;link</a>.</p>

<p>I'm a <a data-cke-saved-href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=Subject&amp;body=Body" href="mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=Subject&amp;body=Body">mailto link</a>.</p>
```

Update the `data-` attribute each time you change `href` and things should go right.

Comment: Fighting the exact same problem today.  Much obliged!